# Use watchdog along with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

So I have a small script which monitors files for changes/modifications, if the file is changed it does a bunch of stuff with it like:

```
class Event(LoggingEventHandler):
def dispatch(self, event):
    #Do something here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    event_handler = Event()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, my_path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

And it works great. But I have another script with bunch of Tkinter widgets(typical tk app with `mainloop()`). Now, When user presses a certain button I want to call watchdog to monitor file changes like before and call `dispatch()` which does a bunch of stuff to it and updates some tkinter ui widgets like progressbars all in the same script.

Pretty new to this GUI stuff, can't figure out how to make watchdog loop and `root.mainloop` work together. How can it be done?

Answer (score 9):

Watchdog runs in its own thread, so there's not much you need to do. If you want to modify the GUI based on an event, you should set up a thread-safe queue. Tkinter widgets shouldn't be modified by more than one thread so the common pattern is to use a thread safe queue to communicate between threads.

The following example places a watchdog event on a queue and uses `event_generate` to send a signal from the observer to the GUI whenever a watchdog event is detected. I don't know with absolute certainty that the following will work in all cases, because I only have access to a linux box to test it at the moment. However, it seems to work ok on linux.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

from Queue import Queue
import sys

class CustomHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, app):
        FileSystemEventHandler.__init__(self)
        self.app = app
    def on_created(self, event): app.notify(event)
    def on_deleted(self, event): app.notify(event)
    def on_modified(self, event): app.notify(event)
    def on_moved(self, event): app.notify(event)

class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else "/tmp"
        handler = CustomHandler(self)
        self.observer = Observer()
        self.observer.schedule(handler, path, recursive=True)

        self.queue = Queue()
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.text = tk.Text(self.root)
        self.text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.text.insert("end", "Watching %s...\n" % path)

        self.root.bind("<Destroy>", self.shutdown)
        self.root.bind("<<WatchdogEvent>>", self.handle_watchdog_event)

        self.observer.start()

    def handle_watchdog_event(self, event):
        """Called when watchdog posts an event"""
        watchdog_event = self.queue.get()
        print("event type:", type(watchdog_event))
        self.text.insert("end", str(watchdog_event) + "\n")

    def shutdown(self, event):
        """Perform safe shutdown when GUI has been destroyed"""
        self.observer.stop()
        self.observer.join()

    def mainloop(self):
        """Start the GUI loop"""
        self.root.mainloop()

    def notify(self, event):
        """Forward events from watchdog to GUI"""
        self.queue.put(event)
        self.root.event_generate("<<WatchdogEvent>>", when="tail")

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```